# Simple diff utility in Java using OOP take 2

Tags: java, algorithm, file, edit-distance

(See the previous iteration [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277868/simple-diff-utility-in-java-using-oop).)

After further revising my code, I have:

**`com.github.coderodde.diff.Diff.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.diff;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Diff {

    public static final class Difference {

        public enum Direction {
            EQUAL,
            INSERT,
            DELETE,
        }

        private final Direction direction;
        private final String line;

        public Difference(Direction direction, String line) {
            this.direction = direction;
            this.line = line;
        }

        public Direction getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        public String getLine() {
            return line;
        }
    }

    private static final String NL = System.lineSeparator();
    private static final String HELP_MESSAGE = 
            "java -jar Diff.jar OLD_FILE NEW_FILE";

    private final List<String> oldLines;
    private final List<String> newLines;
    private final int[][] matrix;

    public Diff(List<String> oldSourceLines, List<String> newSourceLines) {
        this.oldLines = Objects.requireNonNull(oldSourceLines);
        this.newLines = Objects.requireNonNull(newSourceLines);
        this.matrix = new int[oldSourceLines.size() + 1]
                             [newSourceLines.size() + 1];
    }

    public List<Difference> compute() {
        computeLongestCommonSubsequenceMatrix();
        return buildDiff();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(HELP_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            List<String> oldLines = readFile(new File(args[0]));
            List<String> newLines = readFile(new File(args[1]));

            Diff diff = new Diff(oldLines, newLines);
            System.out.println(combine(diff.compute()));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("I/O failed: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static String combine(List<Difference> differences) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Difference difference : differences) {
            switch (difference.getDirection()) {
                case INSERT:
                    stringBuilder.append("+ ");
                    break;

                case DELETE:
                    stringBuilder.append("- ");
                    break;

                case EQUAL:
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Unknown enum: " + difference.getDirection());
            }

            stringBuilder.append(difference.getLine()).append(NL);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
    }

    // Reads all the file lines into a list and returns the list in question.
    private static List<String> readFile(File file) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
    }

    // This algorithm solves the Longest Common Subsequence problem. The 
    // alphabet is not assumed to be a customary alphabet, but rather all 
    // possible strings over a simple alphabet.
    private void computeLongestCommonSubsequenceMatrix() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= oldLines.size(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= newLines.size(); ++j) {
                if (oldLines.get(i - 1)
                        .equals(newLines.get(j - 1))) {
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
                } else {
                    matrix[i][j] = Math.max(matrix[i - 1][j], 
                                            matrix[i][j - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // The entry point for the algorithm that reconstructs the LCS from the 
    // matrix.
    private List<Difference> buildDiff() {
        List<Difference> differences = new ArrayList<>();

        buildDiff(differences,
                  oldLines.size() - 1, 
                  newLines.size() - 1);

        return differences;
    }

    // Reconstructs the diff content from the LCS matrix.
    private void buildDiff(List<Difference> differences,
                           int i, 
                           int j) {
        if (i >= 0 
                && j >= 0 
                && oldLines.get(i).equals(newLines.get(j))) {
            buildDiff(differences,
                      i - 1, 
                      j - 1);

            differences.add(
                    new Difference(
                            Difference.Direction.EQUAL, 
                            oldLines.get(i)));
        } else if (j > 0 && (i == 0 || matrix[i][j - 1] >= matrix[i - 1][j])) {
            buildDiff(differences,
                      i, 
                      j - 1);

            differences.add(
                    new Difference(
                            Difference.Direction.INSERT,
                            newLines.get(j)));
        } else if (i > 0 && (j == 0 || matrix[i][j - 1] < matrix[i - 1][j])) {
            buildDiff(differences,
                      i - 1, 
                      j);

            differences.add(
                    new Difference(
                            Difference.Direction.DELETE, 
                            oldLines.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: In your previous iteration, it has been noted in the answers using `i` and `j` as parameters for `buildDiff` is unreadable. Yet it seems you still use them here. Did you disagree with that part of the answer?

Comment: You have a point. It just didn’t reach my attention.